# Importing python module as object attribute

Tags: python-2.7, syntax-error, python-import

Why does the following code throw a syntax error?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        import numpy as self.np
```

The following works of course:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        import numpy
        self.np = numpy
```

It sounds like the syntax does not allow identifiers that are object attributes. But I don't see any reason why it should not.

Comment: try `import numpy as np`

Comment: @William, My point is that I want to assign numpy as an object attribute, not a temporary variable.

Comment: your second code will solve the problem. also you can use `import numpy as np` then `self.IShouldNotBeStubbornBecauseIDidNotCreatePythonThusICanNotMakeItWorksAsIWant = np` after than in any method inside your class you can call your `self.IShouldNotBe...`